# Create a custom validator for number field

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I need a validator for a form field `<input type='number>` to limit the range.

I tried to build one similar to the existing (like `NgModelMaxLengthValidator`) but it extends the private class `_NgModelValidator`, so this approach seems not to work.

Is it possible to add custom validators to the built in validation system?
What is a good approach?

Comment: The range (min/max) validation has been added to AngularDart (github repo only yet)